# Test a create-react-app index.js file

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I would like to have 100% coverage on my project.

[image: img]

In order to do so, I need to test my index.js file which is very basic :

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I can't find how to test this.
When creating a function such as :

`index.js`

```
const index = (div) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div || document.getElementById('root'));
};
```

and then testing it :

`index.test.js`

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  index(div);
});
```

I get an error when importing `index`:
Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

PS:

Note that I already have the following test, working perfectly :

`App.test.jsx`

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, div);
});
```

Comment: can you also please clarify in your intent, I am assuming you meant that you do not want to ignore the file just to get 100% coverage. Some of of the answers have suggested suppression, which is not a solution. See my recent answer for React 18

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main question is what you want to test there. If you want to test that **your** code works correct, write a unit test that spies on `ReactDOM.render` and mocks `document.getElementById('root')`. Cause this is all your code does, calling `ReactDOM.render` with our App component and a specific `div`.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
...
jest.mock('react-dom', ()=> ({render: jest.fn()}))


it('renders without crashing', () => {

  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, div);
  global.document.getElementById = (id) => id ==='root' && div
  expect(ReactDOM.render).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)
});
```

If you want test that the app really starts in your page, you should write integration test with Selenium or Nightwatch.js

To just get 100% coverage you can also ignore this file by adding it to the [`coveragePathIgnorePatterns`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#coveragepathignorepatterns-array-string) in your jest settings

Comment: What I want to do is either ignore index.js from jest coverage, or actually have a test for my index file in order to have 100% coverage from jest --coverage.

adding `coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["src/index.js"]` to `package.json` doesn't work...

Comment: Updating my answer, even I would argue that 100% coverage should not be a goal in testing.

Comment: `react-scripts test --env=jsdom --coverage --collectCoverageFrom=src/**/*.js? --collectCoverageFrom=!src/index.js` works, but setting directly `collectCoverageFrom` in `package.json` doesn't work.

`coveragePathIgnorePattern` doesn't seem to work at all...

Comment: @ThomasSauvajon Including `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` seems to be working just fine with `react-scripts: 1.0.17` (includes react v16)

Comment: CreateReactApp application is not supporting   
      coveragePathIgnorePatterns use                             
       collectCoverageFrom  instead.

Answer (score 34):

If 100% coverage on your project is your goal and the code in your `index.js` file is trivial, then it might be a good option to exclude the file from the coverage report, as Andreas Köberle points out in his answer.

Create-react-app currently only supports these four keys in the Jest configuration ([source](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#configuration)):

[`collectCoverageFrom`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#collectcoveragefrom-array)
[`coverageReporters`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#coveragereporters-array-string)
[`coverageThreshold`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#coveragethreshold-object)
[`snapshotSerializers`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#snapshotserializers-array-string)

This is why

> `coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["src/index.js"]`

won't work.

Add following code to the most outer scope of your `package.json` file:

```
"jest": {
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "!src/index.js"
  ]
}
```

In the image below you see the output of a test run with this code added to the `package.json` of the initial app created with create-react-app v1.4.3. Note that the `index.js` file doesn't show up in the report anymore and also doesn't affect the coverage percentage.

[image: Coverage report]

Comment: I am not sure if I agree this is a solution, it sounds like gaming the system to get the results you want, it is a bad practice. Answer by Shiraz should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 30):

This is how I've tested index.js

#### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

#### index.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

jest.mock("react-dom", () => ({ render: jest.fn() }));

describe("Application root", () => {
  it("should render without crashing", () => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "root";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    require("./index.js");
    expect(ReactDOM.render).toHaveBeenCalledWith(<App />, div);
  });
});
```

Comment: damn -- wish I could get this to work. I keep getting `null` as the value of `div`.

Comment: @rpivovar, are you saying that `document.createElement("div")` returns `null`?

Comment: If you're using React strict mode, remember to add wrappers also to the test file: `.toHaveBeenCalledWith(<React.StrictMode><App /></React.StrictMode>,div);`

Otherwise you'll receive `<UNDEFINED><App /></UNDEFINED>` test failure

Comment: This is a great answer it worked, I am going to post a new one that will work for React 18. Thank you!

Comment: @MGDeveloper I would definitely look forward to that. I am currently trying to test my src/index.js file, I do most of my routing in here, any idea how this would work?

Something along the lines of this: [https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-tree-5jev9n?file=/src/App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-tree-5jev9n?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @0x5929. I have posted the answer for React 18. Please see and at the bottom of the this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I found an [article online](https://wetainment.com/testing-indexjs/) that explains this way to write the test...

```
// index.test.js
import Index from './index.js';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  expect(JSON.stringify(
    Object.assign({}, Index, { _reactInternalInstance: 'censored' })
  )).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Now change the index.js file accordingly:

```
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

export default ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root') || document.createElement('div')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending on [dcastil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49110498/1505348), here's how to skip these trivial files for a TypeScript project:

1. Edit `package.json`
2. At the root level add the following snippet

   ```
   {
     ...rest of existing props,
     "jest": {
       "collectCoverageFrom": [
         "src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
         "!src/serviceWorker.ts",
         "!src/index.tsx"
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
3. Save and re-run coverage

By now coverage should be higher.

Answer (score 0):

Here what i did and looks like it works just perfect (100% coverage, app doesn't break):

```
// src/index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

import './index.css';

export const ReactStrictMode = <React.StrictMode>
  <App />
</React.StrictMode>

export const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')

ReactDOM.render(
  ReactStrictMode,
  rootElement
);
```

and then in `index.spec.js`:

```
// src/index.spec.js
/* eslint-env jest */
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { ReactStrictMode, rootElement } from './index'

jest.mock('react-dom', () => ({ render: jest.fn() }))

describe('index.js', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    ReactDOM.render(ReactStrictMode, rootElement)
    expect(ReactDOM.render).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ReactStrictMode, rootElement)
  })
})
```

Comment: The second line in your test body looks promising. However, in the first line, you basically do the expected thing, so the second line will be obviously true. You are testing your test. ;) How about removing the first line and letting the implemented code do that call, so your test will actually test, that the implementation and not itself...

Answer (score 0):

> Added a couple of more test cases. Any feedback would be appreciated...

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

afterEach(cleanup);

// jest.mock will mock all the function using jest.fn() that is present inside the react-dom library
jest.mock("react-dom");

describe("Testing Application Root", () => {
  it("should render without crashing", () => {
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = "root";
      document.body.appendChild(div);
      require("./index");
      expect(ReactDOM.render).toHaveBeenCalledWith(<App />, div);
  });
    
  it("should render the app inside div which has root id", () => {
    expect(global.document.getElementById("root")).toBeDefined();
  });
  
  it("should render App component", () => {
    expect(App).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer above by Shiraz. This is essentially the same solution but for React 17/18. Also it provides some additional test coverage.

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode />,
);
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const render= jest.fn().mockName('render');

jest.mock('react');
jest.mock('react-dom', () => ({
  createRoot: jest.fn().mockName('createRoot')
}));

let documentSpy=jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById')


describe('Entry point index test', () => {

  const doc =document.createElement('div');
  doc.setAttribute('id', 'root');

  beforeEach(() => {
    ReactDOM.createRoot.mockReturnValue({render});
    require("../index.js");
   });

  it('should call ReactDOM.createRoot once', () => {
    expect(ReactDOM.createRoot).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('should call document.getElementById with root once', () => {
    expect(documentSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(documentSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('root');
  });

  it('should call render with React.StrictMode', () => {
    expect(render).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(render).toHaveBeenCalledWith( <React.StrictMode />,);
  });

});
```

Comment: Getting `TypeError : Cannot destructure property 'Consumer' of 'ThemeContext' as it is undefined.`