TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined
Originally pushed code to remote and ran CI/CD pipeline which shown error listed below. But error wasn't happening in my local environment.
After so much troubleshooting in the pipleline the decision was made to delete the local repo to start from zero. After doing so the error was also replicated in local.
Abou the error:
Used the below code found at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57269873/3529794
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

jest.mock("react-dom", () => ({ render: jest.fn() }));

describe("Application root", () => {
  it("should render without crashing", () => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "root";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    require("./index.js");
    expect(ReactDOM.render).toHaveBeenCalledWith(<App />, div);
  });
});

Then execute 'npm run test' which successfully runs all tests under the test folder except for the one above.
The test throws error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined

      1 | import React from 'react';
    > 2 | import {Initialization} from 'coveo-search-ui';
        | ^

      at Function.PublicPathUtils.parseScriptDirectoryPath (node_modules/coveo-search-ui/bin/js/src/utils/PublicPathUtils.ts:67:19)
      at Function.PublicPathUtils.getDynamicPublicPath (node_modules/coveo-search-ui/bin/js/src/utils/PublicPathUtils.ts:41:19)
      at Function.PublicPathUtils.detectPublicPath (node_modules/coveo-search-ui/bin/js/src/utils/PublicPathUtils.ts:17:49)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/coveo-search-ui/bin/js/src/Eager.ts:4:17)
      at __webpack_require__ (node_modules/coveo-search-ui/bin/js/webpack/bootstrap 9f061b213793663de5ee:136:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/coveo-search-ui/bin/js/CoveoJsSearch.js:121684:18)
      at __webpack_require__ (node_modules/coveo-search-ui/bin/js/webpack/bootstrap 9f061b213793663de5ee:136:1)
      at node_modules/coveo-search-ui/bin/js/webpack/bootstrap 9f061b213793663de5ee:231:1
      at node_modules/coveo-search-ui/bin/js/CoveoJsSearch.js:245:10
      at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (node_modules/coveo-search-ui/bin/js/webpack/universalModuleDefinition:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/coveo-search-ui/bin/js/webpack/universalModuleDefinition:10:2)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.js:2:1) 

Context:

Main app package.json coveo dependency listed as "coveo-search-ui": "^2.10096.0",
App launches and runs fine. No issues there.
Test passes with same code in a different developer's machine. Which remember it was also passing in my machine before wiping the repo out of my local.
My machine uses node v14.17.4

Help is appreciated.

This might be a good bug report for a library or tool, but for a public audience with no access to the code I'm not sure this is enough info for anyone to help. Please include any relevant code to the issue by making an [edit] to your question
